# What is the symbol on Gaara's gourd?

Tags: naruto

Gaara has a symbol that reads "WMW" on his Sand gourd. What does this symbol mean? Is it kanji or just some random symbol?

[image]

Comment: I don't think that says "WMW"... it just looks like some sort of design/pattern (for aesthetic purposes). At any rate, it isn't anything Japanese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Naruto wiki site](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sand_Gourd):

> Gaara carries around this giant calabash-shaped gourd covered in designs and filled with his chakra-infused sand which he can freely manipulate.

It's just a design on the gourd and doesn't hold any particular meaning.

Answer (score -1):

there is likely no meaning to the presence of the symbol aside from looks but it is one japanese "letter" from Katakana written system, not Kanji. It is ヨ . which is pronounced yo